# Showing popup according to the header nav link

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I am showing templates in popups according to the user navigation links. It works for me, but, is this the correct way to do it?

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.service('modalService', function( $rootScope ) {


  this.hide = function () {

    this.show = false;


  }

  this.showIt = function () {

    this.show = true;

  }

  this.setCategory = function ( category ) {

     return this.showPath = category+'.html'

  }

  this.showCategory = function (category) {

    this.setCategory( category )
    $rootScope.$apply();
  }

})

app.controller('header', function($scope) {

  $scope.view = "home view";

});

app.controller('home', function($scope, modalService) {

  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.service = modalService; 

});

//header directive

app.directive('headerDir', function( modalService) {

  return {
      restrict : "E",
      replace:true,
      templateUrl:'header.html',
      scope:{},
      link : function (scope, element, attrs) {


         element.on('click', '.edit', function () {
            modalService.showIt();
            modalService.showCategory('edit');
         });

         element.on('click', '.service', function () {
           modalService.showIt();
           modalService.showCategory('service');

         })

      }
  }

});

app.directive('popUpDir', function () {

  return {
    replace:true,
    restrict:"E",
    templateUrl : "popup.html"
  }

})
```

Click on the top link to show the popup, and click on the screen to hide the popup.

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3o9aAP49pjyZDoSjNPig?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>   this.hide = function () {
>
>     this.show = false;
>
>
>   }
>
>   this.showIt = function () {
>
>     this.show = true;
>
>   }
> ```

You have extraneous lines everywhere, and extraneous space everywhere, trim it down.

```
this.hide   = function(){ this.show = false; }
this.showIt = function(){ this.show = true;  }
```

---

On the other hand, here, you're missing space (*but also have extra space*):

> ```
>   this.setCategory = function ( category ) {
>
>      return this.showPath = category+'.html'
>                                    ^^^
>   }
> ```

should be:

```
this.setCategory = function(category){ this.showPath = category + '.html'; }
```

The `return` is redundant, as the value goes nowhere in `showCategory`.

---

> ```
>      element.on('click', '.edit', function () {
>         modalService.showIt();
>         modalService.showCategory('edit');
>      });
>
>      element.on('click', '.service', function () {
>        modalService.showIt();
>        modalService.showCategory('service');
> ```

This is redundant, pass the `.service` / `.edit` in as a variable.